# Set Focus OnNavigatedTo in Prism for WPF Application

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism-4

I would like on navigation between views in a WPF application using Prism to have the ability to set focus to sepecific textboxes so a user can perform navigation and then begin typing in the relevant textbox without a second click into the textbox.

I have an application built with Prism that has a Shell with a `ContentControl` "MainContentRegionContentControl".  I then have some buttons across the top when on clicking them I do a `region.RequestNavigate("UserControlToLoad")`.  On the `UserControl` I have the `OnNavigatedTo` and in that method I call `this.MainTextBox.Focus()`.

The above doesn't appear to work, the navigation appears to work and the `OnNavigatedTo` method is called, but the textbox doesn't have focus.

I've added `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` to the textbox, but this hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Loaded()` method for each page instead of `OnNavigatedTo()` and `TextBox.Focus()` will work fine then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following... In your View implement IActiveAware

```
class ViewModel : IActiveAware
{
    #region IActiveAware Members
    private bool isActive = false;

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return isActive;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != isActive)
            {
                isActive = value;
                OnIsActiveChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }


    public event EventHandler IsActiveChanged = delegate { };

    protected virtual void OnIsActiveChanged(EventArgs args)
    {
        IsActiveChanged(this, args);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

`OnIsActiveChanged`, try setting focus to the TextBox you'd like to focus when IsActive becomes true

Comment: same result as OnNavigatedTo unfortunately